# Compiling caffe for windows: libraries (LNK2001: unresolved external symbol)

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2013, caffe

I'm trying to compile caffe for windows to run dreamify python code;
For some reason when compiling it searches for both python 2.7 and 3.5. As a result I now have 3 different libs -- python27, python35 and python35 from anaconda (my main environment);
Compiling in Visual Studio 2013;
Although building caffe still returns an error:

`Error 2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct _object *
 __cdecl boost::python::detail::init_module(struct PyModuleDef &,void (__cdecl*)(void))"
 (?init_module@detail@python@boost@@YAPEAU_object@@AEAUPyModuleDef@@P6AXXZ@Z)   <path>pycaffe\_caffe.obj    pycaffe
 Error  3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
 externals  <path>\Build\x64\Release\_caffe.pyd pycaffe`

All I've got through search is that it's still a library issue, but nothing specific - I don't even know which library is wrong since pycaffe asks for both 27 and 35 for some reason;

So my questions are
1) Why does caffe for windows need 2 different python libraries
2) How can I definitevely pinpoint where it crashes;

If it helps here's where the error occurs:

`PythonPreBuild.cmd : Generating src\caffe\proto\caffe.pb.h with python bindings
     Creating library <path>\windows\..\Build\x64\Release\_caffe.lib and object <path>\windows\..\Build\x64\Release\_caffe.exp`

Comment: According to the [instructions here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) you should use Miniconda 2.7, with it added to `PATH`, with conda-installed numpy, scipy, matplotlib, scikit-image, and pip, and pip-installed protobuf. Then copy "windows\CommonSettings.props.example" to "windows\CommonSettings.props" and enable `PythonSupport`. Note that it configures `PythonDir` to "C:\Miniconda2" for setting the lib and include directories, which I assume is the default installation directory for Miniconda 2.7.

Comment: I'll try, although this is not relevant - this is a experimental repository, caffe-windows in now in the [official one](https://github.com/microsoft/caffe)